# Datatable with SqlGeography column can't be serialized to xml correctly with loss of Lat,Long and other elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datatable, sqlgeography

I tried to serialize a DataTable object to xml.
The DataTable has a column with type 'geography', which contains instances of type [SqlGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx).

The following code is used to serialize the datatable to xml:

```
            var writer = new StringWriter();             
            dt.WriteXmlSchema(writer); //get schema
            //serialize to xml
            dt.WriteXml(writer);
            Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
```

The generated xml string is not complete with the loss of all Geo elements Lat,Long,...

It contains only STSrid element.

The following is the generated xml string:

```
        <table>
            <f1 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <STSrid>4326</STSrid>
            </f1>
            <id>1</id>
          </table>
          <table>
            <f1 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <STSrid>4326</STSrid>
            </f1>
            <id>2</id>
          </table>
```

This means that you can't use the xml for deserialization, and you loose the SqlGeography data.

The schema is generated correctly:

```
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
          <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="table">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="f1" msdata:DataType="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
```

You can find the [complete C# program online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpcliP)  to show the problem.

**My Question:**

1) What I missed to get a valid  xml serialization for SqlGeography column?

2) Is't a bug in the DataTable.WriteXml method to handle a complex object?

Comment: Why not use dt.WriteXml("filename) instead of serializing?

Comment: `DataTable.WriteXml()` internally uses `XmlSerializer` to serialize complex column values.  And since `Lat` and `Long` are both get-only, and [`SqlGeography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) doesn't implement `IXmlSerializable`, there's no way this is going to work, since `XmlSerializer` doesn't serialize get-only properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTable.WriteXml()` internally uses [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to serialize complex column values. And since [`Lat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.lat.aspx) and [`Long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.long.aspx) are both get-only, and [`SqlGeography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) doesn't implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx), there's no way this is going to work, since `XmlSerializer` doesn't serialize get-only properties.

Instead, you're going to need to replace instances of `SqlGeography` with some appropriate [data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) in order to serialize it.  But, what should that DTO contain and how should it be created?  There are several options:

1. Manually convert to and from [GML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language) using [`SqlGeography.AsGml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.asgml.aspx) and [`SqlGeography.GeomFromGml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.geomfromgml.aspx).

   In this scenario, your DTO would look like something this:

   ```
   public class SqlGeographyDTO
   {
       const int DefaultSRID = 4326; // TODO: check if this is the correct default.

       public int? STSrid { get; set; }

       public XElement Geography { get; set; }

       public static implicit operator SqlGeographyDTO(SqlGeography geography)
       {
           if (geography == null || geography.IsNull)
               return null;
           return new SqlGeographyDTO
           {
               STSrid = geography.STSrid.IsNull ? (int?)null : geography.STSrid.Value,
               Geography = geography.AsGml().ToXElement(),
           };
       }

       public static implicit operator SqlGeography(SqlGeographyDTO dto)
       {
           if (dto == null)
               return SqlGeography.Null;
           var sqlXml = dto.Geography.ToSqlXml();
           var geography = SqlGeography.GeomFromGml(sqlXml, dto.STSrid.GetValueOrDefault(DefaultSRID));
           return geography;
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return Geography == null ? "" : Geography.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
       }
   }

   public static class XNodeExtensions
   {
       public static SqlXml ToSqlXml(this XNode node)
       {
           if (node == null)
               return SqlXml.Null;
           using (var reader = node.CreateReader())
           {
               return new SqlXml(reader);
           }
       }
   }

   public static class SqlXmlExtensions
   {
       public static XElement ToXElement(this SqlXml sql)
       {
           if (sql == null || sql.IsNull)
               return null;
           using (var reader = sql.CreateReader())
               return XElement.Load(reader);
       }
   }
   ```

   Since GML is an XML-based format the result will be parsable by any XML parser.  Note, however, that conversion from and to GML is documented not to be precise.

   Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iRhmwN).

   (As an aside: `AsGml()` returns an object of type [`SqlXml`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SqlXml.cs) which implements `IXmlSerializable`, so it would seem possible to include the returned `SqlXml` directly in the DTO.  Unfortunately, testing reveals that either `AsGml()` or [`SqlXml.WriteXml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506314(v=vs.110).aspx) seem to have a bug: an XML declaration is always included, even when the XML is being written as a nested child element of an outer container element. Thus the resulting, serialized XML will be nonconformant and broken.  Parsing to an intermediate `XElement` avoids this bug by stripping the unwanted declaration.)
2. Manually convert to and from Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Well-Known Text (WKT) representation augmented with any Z (elevation) and M (measure) values by using [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.tostring.aspx) with [`SqlGeography.STGeomFromText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stgeomfromtext.aspx).

   In this implementation your DTO would look something like:

   ```
   public class SqlGeographyDTO
   {
       const int DefaultSRID = 4326; // TODO: check if this is the correct default.

       public int? STSrid { get; set; }

       public string Geography { get; set; }

       public static implicit operator SqlGeographyDTO(SqlGeography geography)
       {
           if (geography == null || geography.IsNull)
               return null;
           return new SqlGeographyDTO
           {
               STSrid = geography.STSrid.IsNull ? (int?)null : geography.STSrid.Value,
               Geography = geography.ToString(),
           };
       }

       public static implicit operator SqlGeography(SqlGeographyDTO dto)
       {
           if (dto == null)
               return SqlGeography.Null;
           var geography = SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(dto.Geography), dto.STSrid.GetValueOrDefault(DefaultSRID));
           return geography;
       }
   }
   ```

   Again this implementation might lose precision, but has the advantage of being usable with many formats and serializers including JSON and Json.NET.  This seems to be the approach used by [`ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters/SqlServerGeographyTypeConverter`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters/SqlServerGeographyTypeConverter.cs), for instance.

   Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HVLKcT) courtesy of @M.Hassan.
3. Manually convert from and to a `byte []` binary representation using [`SqlGeography.Write(BinaryWriter)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.write.aspx) with [`SqlGeography.Read (BinaryReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.read.aspx).

   In this implementation your DTO class would contain `public byte [] Geography { get; set; }`.

   These methods are documented not to lose precision, but since the binary is opaque you won't be able to document your interchange format.  This seems to be the approach used by [`Dapper.EntityFramework.DbGeographyHandler`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.EntityFramework/DbGeographyHandler.cs).  Note however that Dapper is calling [`STAsBinary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stasbinary.aspx), which, according to the documentation, returns a value that *will not contain any Z or M values carried by the instance.*

Once you have your DTO, you could replace it in your current `DataTable` using one of the answers from, e.g., [How To Change DataType of a DataColumn in a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9028029).

Note - above DTOs are not fully tested.

Comment: You’re the man. Many thanks to that smart solution. I'll test your alternatives and feedback.

Comment: alternative2 of Well-Known Text (WKT)  is working fine for serialization and deserialization. The magic is in the implicit operator.My online test https://dotnetfiddle.net/HVLKcT.

Comment: @M.Hassan - thanks for the fiddle.  Based on that I fixed the XML DTO -- apparently the `SqlXml` returned by `AsGml()` always includes an XML declaration even when written as a nested child element.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort. Now Alternative 1 (GML) is working fine.  I added two methods GetLat, GetLong to alternative 2, https://dotnetfiddle.net/HVLKcT